# Last CSS rule in file is overridden by previous rule in the same file

Tags: css, css-selectors

Can you please clarify why the last CSS rule in my file, styles.css, is overridden by a previous entry in the same file?

Here is the Firebug output:

```
padding-top
  (1) .top-bar-section li a:not(.button)    0px      styles.css?mvsvc7 (line 2666)
  (2) .top-bar-section ul li > a            1px      styles.css?mvsvc7 (line 3137)
  (3) .top-bar-section ul li > a            12px     styles.css?mvsvc7 (line 2457)
```

Rule (1) was ultimately applied, but it is declared on line 2666, whereas I would expect rule (2) to be applied which is on line 3137.

Thinking that it was related to the :not pseudo-selector, I removed it, and still observed the same behaviour.

I am using Drupal 7, and I tried running with and without CSS compression and aggregation.

I observe this behaviour on the following browsers:

- Firefox 25.0
- Chrome 30.0.1599.114

Comment: See if you can include a snippet of the generated HTML containing the affected elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely it's simply because rule (1) has a [more specific selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) than the other two rules.

The specificity of the selector in rule (1) is calculated as follows:

```
.top-bar-section li a:not(.button) /* 2 classes, 2 types -> specificity = 0-2-2 */
```

And the specificity of the selector in rule (2) is:

```
.top-bar-section ul li > a         /* 1 class, 3 types   -> specificity = 0-1-3 */
```

Note that combinators like `>` and whitespace don't influence specificity in any way; `li a` and `li > a` are equally specific.

Since there are more class selectors in the first selector (the `:not()` pseudo-class counts as a single class because its argument, `.button`, is a class selector), it is more specific, and so that rule takes precedence.

It's not clear to me why removing the `:not()` selector would still cause it to take precedence, however, since doing so should make it less specific than your last rule, as the result would be as follows:

```
.top-bar-section li a              /* 1 class, 2 types   -> specificity = 0-1-2 */
```

Comment: It seems like `:not` does not add anything to specificity for some reason.  The argument to `:not` does, though.  http://jsfiddle.net/3UunX/

Comment: @Explosion Pills: Correct - I've linked to the spec where it states how to account for `:not()` and its argument.